# Pass variables to res.render in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I'm a beginner in node.js.
 My `index.ejs` file has an included `header.ejs` file. Everything works well except that I cant pass values to the variable `status` in `header.ejs`.

## index.ejs

```
<html>
.
.
<title> <%= title %> </title>
.
.
<% include ../partial/header.ejs %>
.
.
</html>
```

## header.ejs

```
<header>
.
.
<p>logged in status: <%= status %> </p>
.
.
</header>
```

## app.js

```
.
.
.
app.get('/', function(req, res)
{
    // not working :(
    res.render('index', {
        "status":"loggedin",
        "title":"home"
    });
});
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's somewhat of a mess with your structure.

1. `<title>` should be within `<head>`.
2. `<p>` should be within `<body>`.
3. Note that you may have confused `<head>` and `<header>` tags in your templates. You can learn about the difference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3434975/3873012).

Here's an example I expect will work for you:

index.ejs:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title> <%= title %> </title>
</head>
<body>
    <% include ../partial/header %>
</body>
</html>
```

header.ejs:

```
    <p>logged in status: <%= status %> </p>
```

Comment: thank you. I knew that and I'm not confused with header and head. I just shrieked it down to focus on my question. App.js renders index.ejs. But to render index.ejs it need header.ejs to render first. How can I do that? Any alternative methods?

Comment: @WWJ, try to remove the `.ejs` from your include syntax. In EJS you can include any template file as long as your node process has read access to it.

Comment: Yes, perfect. That is what exactly I want.